# Can I use JOLT 'shift' to achieve this and how? Array to map (list to dict) using JOLT

Tags: java, json, jolt, fixed-length-file

I am transforming a large JSON into a fixed-length csv file, at this stage I've cut down the json with a JOLT Remove and I have used a JOLT Shift to put the remaining parameters into the input provided.

**I have the output from a previous JOLT 'shift' resembling the following:**
**This will form the input for a JOLT "shift"**

```json
{
  "TIME": "2023-02-27T16:26:25Z",
  "FORENM": [
    "JILL",
    "LITA"
  ],
  "SURNAME": [
    "JaCK",
    "HANCOCK"
  ],
  "TOWN": [
    "CHRISTCHURCH",
    "GLASGOW",
    "LAZYTOWN",
    null,
    "TELETUBBYHILL",
    "BALAMORY"
  ]
}
```

**I want the output to resemble the following:**

```json
{
  "MAIN-TOWN": "CHRISTCHURCH",
  "MAIN_FORENM": "JILL",
  "MAIN_SURNAME": "JaCK",
  "TIME": "2023-02-27T16:26:25Z",
  "ALT-TOWN": "TELETUBBYHILL",
  "ALT_FORENM": "LITA",
  "ALT_SURNAME": "HANCOCK"
}
```

**Is this possible? If so, can I do it with a **shift** transform? Could someone show me to I would be able to map a certain index from an array in the input. For example, from the town array I want to map **`"MAIN-TOWN"`** to index 0 of the **`"TOWN"`** array from the input and index 4 to **`"ALT-TOWN"`**.**

Comment: oops that was an accident, but later on I would like to have a field that takes the initial, rather than the name.. not right now though. it should be LITA as in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better using a **modify-overwrite** transformation and then get rid of the redundant attributes by **remove** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "MAIN-TOWN": "=firstElement(@(1,TOWN))",
      "MAIN_FORENM": "=firstElement(@(1,FORENM))",
      "MAIN_SURNAME": "=firstElement(@(1,SURNAME))",
      "ALT-TOWN": "=elementAt(4,@(1,TOWN))",
      "ALT_FORENM": "=lastElement(@(1,FORENM))",
      "ALT_SURNAME": "=lastElement(@(1,SURNAME))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "FORENM|SURNAME|TOWN": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to map the first initial of the name instead of the entire name as a separate map. E.g. a field MAIN-FORENM: JILL, and a new map MAIN-INITIAL: J

Comment: You can add `"MAIN-INITIAL": "=substring(@(1,MAIN_FORENM),0,1)"` @AzizR.

Comment: If I wanted this to maintain the order of items, how can I retain 'TIME' within this. I.e. can I put in a parameter that will map TIME it's original value and keep it in it's original place without having to use another operation?

Comment: In that case you would need one more spec to add : `{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "MAIN-TOWN": "&",
      "MAIN_FORENM": "&",
      "MAIN_SURNAME": "&",
      "TIME": "&",
      "ALT-TOWN": "&",
      "ALT_FORENM": "&",
      "ALT_SURNAME": "&"
    }
  }` @AzizR.